# problem creating tex from tex because of missing space

Tags: macros, external-files, viewers, write, renewcommand

I have saved a name in \Name. It is ABC.
So actually I wrote both possibilities
this one

```
\immediate\write\file{\read\noexpand\NoFile to  \\Name}
```

and this one

```
\immediate\write\file{\read\noexpand\NoFile to  \ \Name}.
```

In the first one I just get this in my document

```
\read\noexpand\NoFile to  \\Name
```

With the other one I get this

```
\read\noexpand\NoFile to  \ ABC
```

And with both I can't work.

what I want actually get is that this space is removed like this

```
\read\noexpand\NoFile to \ABC
```

So I can immediately can use it in other documents.

But I don't know how to remove the space between \ and \Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

several possibilities eg

```
    \immediate\write\file{\read\noexpand\NoFile to \expandafter\string\csname\NAME\endcsname}
```

Comment: Thank you it works very well !!!

Comment: another one is `\@backslashchar\Name`

Comment: @plante yes I wondered about suggesting that but didn't want to makeatletter just for one command.